Understanding the Projection of a Subset $H$ as a Cylinder in the Context of Fuchsian Groups
I'm currently studying Beardon's book and I'm having trouble understanding a passage in Section 10.4 regarding the signature of a Fuchsian group. Beardon mentions that
§10.4. The Signature of a Fuchsian Group

Let $G$ be a finitely generated non-elementary Fuchsian group. Consider the Nielsen region $N$ for $G$ and corresponding quotient space. The argument given in Section 10.3 shows that the boundary of $N$ consists of all axes of all boundary hyperbolic elements in $G$. Let $A$ be one such axis with stabilizer generated by $h$ and let $H$ be the component of $\Delta$ is—$A$ not containing $N$. Obviously, $H$ is stable with respect to $\langle h \rangle$ so the projection of $H$ into $\Delta / G$ is topologically a cylinder.

Here, how can I imagine that the projection of $H$ as a cylinder?

Did you work out the case of cyclic groups $G$? This is the key for understanding the general case.

@MoisheKohan Thank you for your answer! Sorry, I'm not quite sure what you meant by working out or general case but I'm understanding that a cyclic subgroup of G can be classified into elliptic (e.g., rotations by $\pi/3$ s.t. a finite cyclic group), parabolic (e.g., translations like $f(z) = z+1$ and  $f^n (z) = z + n$ s.t. infinite cyclic), and hyperbolic (e.g., dilations $f(z) = az$, and infinite.) Can you give me how cyclicity of G connects to forming a cyclinder in a quotient space?

The relevant case is when $f$ is hyperbolic. The "general" case is the one of nonelementary groups. I can explain the more precise meaning of my suggestion once you tell me exactly what you mean by "imagine."

Got it! By imagine, I think I didn't understand what the equivalance relation in the quotient space $\Delta / G$ was. But it's just that $z_1 \sim z_2$ if there exists $g \in G$ s.t. $z_1 = g(z_2)$, right?

Right..........
